# how to make one drop down list to link another in php?

Tags: php

Here is my requirement :

When I select a district from the *STATE* drop down list, I want the district present in that state to be listed in the next DISTRICT drop down list.

How can I do this?

Here is my code :

Please sort it out.

```
<?php
//echo "welcome";
include("flash.html");
?>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="menu_style.css" type="text/css" >
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /></head>
<body bgcolor="4B51BA">
<table border=0 width=100% bgcolor="Black" >
<tr>
<td rowspan=3>
<!--<img src="admas.jpg" width=50% height=65% alt=" " border="0"></a></td>-->
<td align=center><font face="algerian" size=7 color ="White">NIVEDI</font></td></tr>

<tr><td><div>
 <ul class="menu"> 

    <li class="top"><target="main" class="top_link"><span>STATE</span></a>

    <select name = "disease">
  <option value="MVM">KARNATAKA</option>
  <option value="ECTRO">MAHARASHTRA</option>
  <option value="LCMO">ANDHRA PRADESH</option>
  <option value="MUV">TAMILNADU</option>
  <option value="KRV">ASSAM</option>
</select>
    </li>

        <li class="top"><target="main" class="top_link"><span>DISTRICT</span></a>
        <select name = "disease">
        <option value="MVM">KARNATAKA</option>
  <option value="ECTRO">MAHARASHTRA</option>
  <option value="LCMO">ANDHRA PRADESH</option>
  <option value="MUV">TAMILNADU</option>
  <option value="KRV">ASSAM</option>
  </select>
        </li>
            <li class="top"><a href="dataentry.php" target="main" class="top_link"><span>ADJ DISTRICT</span></a></li>
                    <li class="top"><a href="dataentry.php" target="main" class="top_link"><span>DISEASE NAME</span></a></li>
                        <li class="top"><target="main" class="top_link"><span>YEAR</span></a>
                        <select name = "year">
                        <option value="MVM">1987</option>
  <option value="ECTRO">1988</option>
  <option value="LCMO">1989</option>
  <option value="MUV">1990</option>
  <option value="KRV">1991</option>
  <option value="MVM">1992</option>
  <option value="ECTRO">1993</option>
  <option value="LCMO"> 1994</option>
  <option value="MUV">1995</option>
  <option value="KRV">1996</option>
  <option value="MVM">1997</option>
  <option value="ECTRO">1998</option>
  <option value="LCMO">1999 </option>
  <option value="MUV">2000</option>
  <option value="KRV">2001</option>
  <option value="MVM">2002</option>
  <option value="ECTRO">2003</option>
  <option value="LCMO">2004 </option>
  <option value="MUV">2005</option>
  <option value="KRV">2006</option>
  <option value="MVM">2007</option>
  <option value="ECTRO">2008</option>
  <option value="LCMO"> 2009</option>
  <option value="MUV">2010</option>
  <option value="KRV">2011</option>
  <option value="MVM">2012</option>
  <option value="ECTRO">2013</option>
  <option value="LCMO">2014 </option>
  <option value="MUV">2015</option>
  <option value="KRV">2016</option>
  <option value="MVM">2017</option>
  <option value="ECTRO">2018</option>
  <option value="LCMO">2019 </option>
  <option value="MUV">2020</option>


                        </li>
                            <li class="top"><a href="dataentry.php" target="main" class="top_link"><span>NO OF OUTBREAKS</span></a></li>



    <li class="top"><a href="CDance.html"  target="main" class="top_link"><span>DATA SEARCH</span></a></li>

    <!--<li class="top"><a href="help.html"  target="main" class="top_link"><span>help</span></a>
    </li>
        <li class="top"><a href="AboutUs.html"  target="main" class="top_link"><span>About Us</span></a></li>
    <li class="top"><a href="Contact.html"  target="main" class="top_link"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
    <li class="top"><a href="feedback1.php"  target="main" class="top_link"><span>Feedback</span></a></li>
    <li class="top"><a href="login.php"  target="main" class="top_link"><span>Login</span></a></li>
    <li class="top"><a href="signup.php"  target="main" class="top_link"><span>Sign Up</span></a></li>
    -->
    </tr>
    </td>
</ul>
</div></table></body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will have to use Jquery or Javascript for that

Comment: use can use ajax for this

Comment: "Please sort it out" is not a question. Please share your research and attempts.

Comment: Which is the state and district here

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX.

For example, if your selects were populated by a different PHP file, ie districtDropdown.php, then you could pass the state to it using GET. Then you could just repopulate the district dropdown every time your state is selected by passing the stateID to districtDropdown.php which should return the select element "districtDropdownSelect".

```
function displayDistrictDropdownWithState(stateID) {
```

if (stateID=="") {
    document.getElementById("districtDropdownSelect").innerHTML="";
    return;
}

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        document.getElementById("districtDropdownSelect").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","/districtDropdown.php?stateID="+stateID,true);
xmlhttp.send();

}

Hope this helps. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery function show() and hide() to make visible of dropdown list box of particular state.

```
if($("#state option:selected").text()=="karnataka")
{
    $("#district_kartnaka").show();
}
else
{
    $("#district_kartnaka").hide();
}
```

like this make the drop down box to make visible if particular state is selected.